# Open iOS web view without cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

If I have an iOS app, how can I open a browser view inside the app (upon the user tapping a button) which contains *no* cookies from *any* domains?

This means the browser view should not remember cookies from the previous time the user opened the browser, nor share cookies with the `Safari` app.

There are now three classes to do web views as far as I understand, `SFSafariViewController`, `WKWebView` and the dated `UIWebView`. Which of these allows what I want to achieve?

Comment: When I Google `ios webview forget cookies` I seem to get a lot of results, do they not work for you?

Comment: If I can parse and delete cookies using this method, then yes! However, the article mentions the ageing UIWebView. Is it possible using the newer WKWebView or SFSafariViewController?

Comment: I'm not an iOS dev (yet) so I don't know, but `ios WKWebView forget cookies` seems to yield some solutions, too

Comment: Actually, disabling cookies altogether would work for me, as described in this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144883/ Can anyone confirm if this prevents all setting of cookies for WKWebView (even for the current browsing session)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WKWebView` is the way to go. Upon initialisation it won't contain any cookies from previous sessions. From the Apple documentation:

> Each web view is given its own Web Content process until an implementation-defined process limit is reached; after that, web views with the same process pool end up sharing Web Content processes.

Furthermore, `WKWebView` is intended as a replacement for the older `UIWebView`.

[SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/index.html) shares cookies and other website data with Safari.

Comment: Brilliant answer! It gives the necessary information to go ahead with WKWebView.