# Using WKWebsiteDataStore on XCode 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, cookies, wkwebview

I tried to delete my wkwebview cookies with the help of `WKWebsiteDataStore`, but `WKWebsiteDataStore` is not supported by my XCode 6.3.2. I am not willing to upgrade to XCode 7. Is there any other option to clear the cookies from `WKWebview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately: no. It's not really a problem with Xcode version, but a problem of iOS version. As you can read in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebsiteDataStore_Class_Ref/), `WKWebsiteDataStore` is only available for `iOS >= 9.0`. So, if you want to use `WKWebsiteDataStore` you have to make iOS 9 as `Deployment Target`.

But, if you want to use iOS9, you have to update your XCode to Xcode7. Indeed, you cannot use iOS 9 on Xcode < 7 ([as you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823478/xcode-6-with-ios-9)).

**So, to sum up**: if you want to use `WKWebsiteDataStore`: update your Xcode to 7+ and set iOS >= 9.0 as you deployment target.

**Edit:** 
After some research, it appears that you have an alternate way to delete cookies on iOS > 8.2. Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144883/clear-cookies-for-wkwebview). But I still think that the best solution is to make the update :)

Comment: Thanks for ur kind answer @ julien Quere.. I will try the solution given in the link and will update the status soon.

Comment: i updated my xcode and OS.. now i can access WKWebsiteDataStore.